# How to route between interfaces

Tags: networking, network-interface, routing

I have the following setup:

```
                         (192.168.4.1)     
   Device A     <------->   device B   <------->   Device C
(192.168.5.84)           (192.168.5.1)          (192.168.4.5)
```

Device B actually has an wifi interface (`wlan0 = 192.168.4.1`) on which an dhcp server is running. Then there is an cables interface (`eth0 = 192.168.5.1`).

What I want to reach is that devices A and C can talk to each other. I have been reading how to get to this result and I have found that I should use routing to accomplish this. I have tried some things and I do not understand why it is not working.

Device A has an static ip (subnet `255.255.255.0` and gateway `192.168.5.1`).

Device C received an ip from the DHCP server (subnet `255.255.255.0` and gateway `192.168.4.1`).

**What I have done:**

On device B I have set enabled the ipforward in `/etc/sysctl`

Added routing:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -s 192.168.5.0/24 -d 192.168.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.4.0/24 -d 192.168.5.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

The thing is that both device A and C are accessible from device B, so this would indicate that it MUST be a routing issue. So my question is, how do I get to the situation where device B routes the traffic from A to C?

---

**Update**: What I failed to mention is that I want to accomplish this result by ONLY changing the settings of device B

Answer (score 13):

No need to use iptables. If you have successfully enabled the ip forwarding (i.e. by setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to `1`), device B will do the job because both networks are directly connected to B. The thing you might missing are the correct routes on device A and C.
On A:

```
ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.5.1
```

On C:

```
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 via 192.168.4.1
```

Comment: Ok yes, this worked! However this made me realize that I did not explain my question properly. The question I now have: how can I accomplish this with ONLY changing the settings of device B? (since C may change a lot and changing A is undesirable)

Comment: The DHCP response could assign 192.168.4.1 as the default gateway for device C, then you don't have to do anything on device C. You will have to arrange something similar for device A, or at least add a route to 192.168.4.0/24 via device B on the default gateway, if A's default gateway is not B; that gateway will send a redirect ICMP to A when A tries to reach 192.168.4.0/24.

Comment: So both A and C should have their default gateway set to B. But hoe does B 'know' it has to route traffic between the two interfaces? I thought the routing rules are meant to accommodate that. If not, what do routing rules do?

Comment: In fact, the current setup has the gateway of A set to `192.168.5.1` and the gateway of C set to `192.168.4.1`. From both A and C I can reach ..5.1 and ..4.1 however I cannot reach each other. What is my setup lacking...?

Comment: Post the output of `ip route show` from every station please.

Comment: OK, I solved it by setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to `1`. I did check that `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` was ok. Furthermore I should add that I also added the default gateway to the DHCP server and I was able to set the default gateway on device A. Thanks!

Comment: Simple and elegant solution - thank you.  
To hopefully save someone else the hour I lost;   if you're using **dnsmasq** on Device B, then ensure either **bogus-priv** is not set or that IPs are in **/etc/hosts** file.    dnsmasq will block fwd'ing upstream otherwise.

Comment: Great answer, many people jump to iptables too quickly :)