# Communicating to a device on another LAN port on a different subnet

Tags: vpn, tunneling

I'm trying to telnet to a device (DEVICE T) via tcp ip with a Linux device in between. I'm not sure if this is feasible but here is what I'm trying to experiment with.

Windows OS with telnet software on port 23.

Linux device with two Ethernet which acts like a gateway. Ethernet A has an ip address from a dhcp and connected to a router as well as the windows OS. They are on IP 192.168.1.x and obtained via dhcp from the router.

Linux device Ethernet B is connected to a device (DEVICE T)  that only accepts telnet connection and echoes to the sender.  They are on 10.0.0.x

How do i make the windows OS telnet to the device T on the other Ethernet and have the linux redirect packets from/to the windows PC and device T. It looks to me that this is some kind of a VPN setup?

I did some research here are the things that i got:
- Use ip tunnel on Linux.
- Use openvpn (later,  if this will work, i would like to try having the Linux device be on internet and have the windows OS communicate to linux device and use the linux as a bridge to communicate to the DEVICE T)
- portmap.io in place of openvpn

I'm not sure where to start and if I'm heading the right path.

By the way,  device T is an enclosed small embedded device with no OS running (not windows nor linux). I hope i can configure everything on the linux box.

Comment: Please read up on routing (your Linux box acts like a router). In particular, all devices on the path (your Windows box) must either also have the correct route, or have a default gateway that goes towards the router.

Comment: Maybe this page helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449468/how-to-route-between-interfaces

Comment: @lnappa Hi, i read that. Thanks for the link. It looks like that's what i need. But when it came to the answer part, the end device needs to issue an route command. On my case, the device T, is neither a Linux nor windows device. It is just a very simple device that only does telnet echoing. I need to see how the routing could be accomplished on the end device, but the device T is an enclosed embedded device.

Comment: thanks. I was able to solve this, used iptables with masquerade.